# Maximum size of intersecting family $F$ such that $|A \cup B| < n$ for all $A,B \in F.$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, graph-theory

> Suppose that $F \subset 2^{[n]}$ is an intersecting family such that $|A \cup B| < n$ for all $A,B \in F.$ Prove that $|F| \leq 2^{n−2}.$

I see that $|F| \leq 2^{n-1}$, since otherwise, by the pigeonhole principle we have a set $A$ and it's complement, which is a contradiction with the assumption of $F$ being an intersecting family. However, I don't know how to use the assumption $|A \cup B| < n$ to get desired bound.

Comment: what is an intersecting family?

Comment: intersecting family means that for any two sets $A, B \in F, A \cap B \neq \emptyset.$

Comment: An intersecting family is a collection $\mathscr S$ of sets with the property that $A\cap B\ne\emptyset$ whenever $A$, $B\in\mathscr S$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can prove it by contradiction, it follows directly from [this lemma](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/268433/for-an-intersecting-family-of-m-sets-there-are-at-least-2m-sets-that-are-con/268436#268436): (if there existed a family $F$ with more than $2^{n-2}$ elements then the set $F'$ of all sets that are a subset of at least one element of $F$ has at least $2^{n-1}+2$ elements and no two of its elements give all of $[n]$ as their union). Note that the proof of the linked result is a little bit similar to what I was trying to do below.

---

Flawed attempt ( in fact the lemma is false, consider taking $n=2k$, and letting $A$ just have the subset $\{1,2,\dots\,k\}$ and letting $B$ contain the $2^n-2^{k+1}+1$ suitable subsets).

Lemma: let $n\geq 2$ and let $A$ and $B$ be non-empty subsets of $2^{[n]}$ such that if $a\in A, b\in B$ then we have $a\cup b \neq [n]$ and $a\cap b\neq \varnothing$, then $|A|+|B|\leq 2^{n-1}$.

Proof: We proceed by induction, the base case is $n=2$, cleary $A$ and $B$ must both be equal and only contain one singleton. So we must have $|A|+|B|=2=2^{n-1}$.

Inductive step: Suppose it is true for $n$ and now let us prove it for $n+1$. Take $A$ and $B$ as in the theorem, now let $A_0=\{a | n\not\in a, a\in A\}$ and $A_1=\{a\setminus \{n\} | n\in a, a\in A\}$. Define $B_0$ and $B_1$ analogously. Notice that $A_0$ and $B_1$ satisfy the conditions of the theorem, because if we have $a\in A_0$ and $b\in B_1$ such that $a\cup b=[n-1]$ this would force the existance of two elements in $A,B$ such that their union is $[n]$, we also must have $a\cap b \neq \varnothing$. It follows that $|A_0|+|B_1|\leq 2^{n-1-1}$ by the induction hypothesis. Analogously $|A_1|+|B_0|\leq 2^{n-1-1}$. It follows that $|A|+|B|\leq 2^{n-1}$.

The gap is when one of the auxiliary sets is empty.

To conclude notice that what you want is just the particular result of this theorem in which $A=B$.

Comment: There is a gap, when one of $A_0$ or $A_1$ is empty, I am working on it.

Comment: @Rose I found a solution with the help of the MO community, I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks so much! But I don't understand the definition of $F′$ a downward-closed and $G$ an upward-claws collection of subsets on an $n$ element. What do they mean?

Comment: It should be upward closed also. A family of sets $S$ is downward closed if whenever $A\in S$ and $B\subseteq A$ we also have $B\in S$. The definition of upward closed is analogous.

Comment: the complete power set is downward closed

Comment: Oh, yeah, of course! I meant upper bound for the intersecting downward closed family?

Comment: no family can be both intersecting and downward closed, because the empty set is contained in any downward closed family.